# override baseHref for ng serve in Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a set "baseHref" to '/bui' in the angular.json file because the static files are deployed there.
If I use ng serve with port 4200 and I navigate to https://localhost:4200 I get the following message: Cannot GET /

This is due to the baseHref. In the past we would use a base href set to '/' and the deployUrl set to '/bui/'. The deployUrl is now deprecated (Angular 14) so we have to use base href.

In production mode on the server the base href is /something-extra/bui/.
We also want to use the application with base href /bui/ in case we test the application with aspnet core and the static files (wwwroot).

I cannot seem to override the baseHref within the ng-serve section of the angular.json file.
How can I override the base href in ng serve modus to '/'?

Answer (score 4):

angular.json

```
.
.
.
 "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "baseHref": "/",
.
.
.
"production": {
              "baseHref": "/bui/",
```

index.html

```
.
.
.
<base href="/">
...
```

Comment: The problem is that my static resources are always in /bui folder. I have sometimes multiple folder per angular application bound to 1 angular.json. Or you mean only ng serve would use the development configuration and all the rest would use the production build? The problem is that I have a localhost on iis express with /bui/ and in production is even different /something/extra/bui/. I need to be able to also test with iis express.

Answer (score 0):

So what i did is
In angular json build:
**"baseHref": "/**

In angular json build production section:
**"baseHref: '/something-extra/bui/'**

In the ng build for testing with wwwroot aspnet core:
**ng build --base-href /bui/**

This way the ng serve root url always gives a result instead of not found which was the original problem.
And it also works in localhost outside webpack dev server with physical files.